# Minimizing sum of variances

Tags: self-study, variance, bootstrap, statistical-learning

This text is from [An Introduction to statistical learning with application in R](http://www.amazon.in/Introduction-Statistical-Learning-Applications-Statistics/dp/1461471370?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=b2873fcd-dac7-4d50-8a4f-ef395872fda3), on page 187$:$

> Suppose that we wish to invest a ﬁxed sum of money in two ﬁnancial assets that yield returns of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, where $X$ and $Y$ are random quantities. We will invest a fraction $α$ of our money in $X$, and will invest the remaining $1−α$ in $Y$. Since there is variability associated with the returns on these two assets, we wish to choose α to minimize the total risk, or variance, of our investment.
>
> In other words, we want to minimize $$Var(\alpha X +(1−\alpha)Y )$$ One can show that the value that minimizes the risk is given by
>
> $$
> α =(VarY-Cov(X,Y)) / (VarX−2Cov(X,Y)+VarY)
> $$

Can you please help me to understand two things

1) How did they arrive at the expression $Var(\alpha X +(1−\alpha)Y )$?

2) How to solve this to get the minimizer equal to 
$$\alpha =(VarY-Cov(X,Y)) / (VarX−2Cov(X,Y)+VarY)$$

Answer (score 3):

Using [standard probabilty results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties),
$$\begin{align*}
f(\alpha) = \text{Var}[\alpha X + (1-\alpha)Y ]  &= \text{Var}(\alpha X)+\text{Var}[(1-\alpha)Y]+2\alpha(1-\alpha)\text{Cov}(X,Y) \\
&=\alpha^2\text{Var}(X)+(1-\alpha)^2\text{Var}(Y)+2\alpha(1-\alpha)\text{Cov}(X,Y)\text{.}
\end{align*}$$
Take the partial with respect to $\alpha$ and set this equal to $0$ to get
$$f^{\prime}(\alpha) = 2\alpha\text{Var}(X)-2(1-\alpha)\text{Var}(Y)+2\text{Cov}(X,Y)(1-2\alpha)=0$$
or
$$\alpha\text{Var}(X)+\alpha\text{Var}(Y)-\text{Var}(Y)-2\alpha\text{Cov}(X,Y)+\text{Cov}(X,Y) = 0\text{,}$$
giving
$$\alpha[\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)-2\text{Cov}(X,Y)]-\text{Var}(Y)+\text{Cov}(X,Y) = 0$$
or
$$\hat{\alpha} = \dfrac{\text{Var}(Y)-\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)-2\text{Cov}(X,Y)}$$
minimizes the desired function.

To show that this value of $\alpha$ is indeed the minimum, compute $f^{\prime\prime}(\hat{\alpha})$ and demonstrate that this is $> 0$. At a glance, this looks like a very time-consuming computation, so I am leaving that as an exercise.

Comment: I know (and why) this value of $\alpha$ does minimize the variance of the portfolio, but you haven't actually shown it.  How do you know, for instance, that you have not found the value of $\alpha$ which maximizes variance? Believe me, I've seen engineers and scientists, some with PhD's, do such thing when blindly plugging and chugging.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I'm too busy to deal with that right now, but I've edited the post with how this would be done.

Comment: @Clarinetist the equation you arrived at doesn't matches to the equation in the book . why so ?

Comment: @user110244 Actually, it is the same as what is in the book. Please reread the notation definitions.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Can you please show me how to compute f′′(α^) and conclude the minimum value for the function. Its quite confusing

Comment: @user110244 I have a feeling you don't have the background to do this. Do you know how to compute a derivative?

Comment: @Clarinetist from my perspective there is a difference in the numerator I guess. Please clarify .In book it is (Cov(X,Y)−VarY) but we solved and get Var(Y)−Cov(X,Y).

Comment: @user110244 No, you read the book incorrectly. What does $\sigma^2_{Y} - \sigma_{XY}$ mean?

Comment: @user110244 Unless there's a typo in your version, I don't know how you're misinterpreting this. There is a free copy of this book available on [this website](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing.pdf), and you can see p. 187 of this.

Comment: @Clarinetist thanks for notifying . Sorry for wasting your time on this silly thing .

Comment: @Clarinetist In case you have time can you solve for f′′(α^) >0 . Thanks

Comment: @user110244 If you know how to compute a derivative, this shouldn't be too hard to do. It will take a lot of time, though, hence I haven't posted it.

Comment: @user110244 please read the guidelines on answering at the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). I think the above answer already does too much, and that it's inappropriate to ask for more; this could easily be homework and it looks like you're asking Clarinetist to just do your homework for you. Instead of that, *show us what you tried*. When you have edited to show some effort on what remains yourself, feel free to flag for reopening.

Comment: Note that there may be more than one way to show that a turning point is a maximum.  While the second derivative would work for this case, you can also consider whether there's another way to argue that it's a maximum (it's really quite easy).

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks you for your kind advice. I searched over the internet and didn't find the second derivative of it and just a bit less confident in the solution which I did as I has been nearly 10 years that I use derivatives.

Comment: Firstly I already explained that you may not need to use derivatives. $\,$ Secondly, did you fail to notice that the function is purely quadratic in $\alpha$? Why would you need to look up how to find the second derivative of a *quadratic*? You should be able to write it down by inspection!  $\:$ Thirdly "I looked at the internet" is NOT showing us how you tried to actually work it out ... it's showing us you again tried to *avoid* doing the work yourself. Invest some effort. You've been given all manner of approaches here.

Answer (score 1):

In general:
$$\mbox{Var} \left( a X + b Y \right) = a^2 \mbox{Var}(x) + b^2 \mbox{Var}(y) + 2ab\mbox{Cov}(X,Y)$$.

Replace $a$ with $\alpha$ and $b$ with $1-\alpha$ and follow the algebra.

Comment: Then use calculus to minimize this expression with respect to $\alpha$

Comment: @Mark You don't really even need calculus for this, though there's nothing hard about doing it that way -- it's a *quadratic* (with a non-negative leading coefficient, what's more). With even a basic knowledge of quadratics, we can simply write down the location of the minimum by inspection (or failing that, simply by completing the square), and the fact that it's actually a minimum follows for the obvious reason.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How did they arrive at the expression $Var(\alpha X +(1−\alpha)Y )$?

Well, if you're investing $\alpha$ in investment with return $X$ and $1-\alpha$ in investment $Y$ then the return of the total investment is $\alpha X +(1−\alpha)Y$.  And the "total risk" (variance) of your return on investment is just the variance of that: $$Var(\alpha X +(1−\alpha)Y ).$$