# Matlab Classification Learner App vs. own code: Why is there a difference between Leave-One-Person-Out and 10-fold Crossvalidation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, matlab

I am trying to find a good model to explain my dataset.

The problem is that I want to do leave-one-person-out cross validation which is not available in the [Matlab Classification Learner App](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationlearner-app.html). So I trained different models (e.g. `Tree`, `SVM`, `KNN`, `LDA`) using functions like `fitctee`, `fitcsvm`, `fitcknn`, and `fitcdiscr`.

Following the `leave-one-person-out` procedure I have found average classification accuracy of about 70% for the best model. However, when I use the App to model the data using `10-Fold cross validation`, it has much better accuracy and `TPR` and `TNR` about 98%.

This is really confusing that why this is happening! I was wondering if there are some steps I am missing when I do the modeling programmatically. Or is there any way to do what the App does by writing scripts and probably customizing the `cross validation` scheme to `leave-one-person-out`?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Leave-One-Out and 10-fold-Crossvalidation do not necessary return comparable results: See for example [10-fold Cross-validation vs leave-one-out cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154830/10-fold-cross-validation-vs-leave-one-out-cross-validation?rq=1), I also suggest to learn about the Bias-Variance-tradeoff in model validation, e.g. by starting off with [Variance and bias in cross-validation: why does leave-one-out CV have higher variance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61783/variance-and-bias-in-cross-validation-why-does-leave-one-out-cv-have-higher-var).

Regarding the specifics of your question:

- When you use as many folds as you have samples in your data set, you force the k-fold-Crossvalidation to become Leave-One-Out (assuming that it is non-stratified crossvalidation).
- The [documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationlearner-app.html) of the Matlab Classification Learner App states, that there is a way to export the steps done by the app to code for later reuse. So you could use this as starting point for your own experiments. Quote:

> To use the model with new data, or to learn about programmatic
>   classification, you can export the model to the workspace or generate
>   MATLAB® code to recreate the trained model

Comment: Thank you @steffen. Yes, I agree they would be different, but this improvement from 70% to around 100% seems a big difference to me. Note that the cross validation I am talking about is different with leave-one-out, since there are more than one sample which belongs to each subject/person. 
I actually try that too. I exported the best model from the App. I used the same model properties to define a new model to be trained and tested in the leave-one-person-out procedure. The model performance did not improve at all.